# Why is Munin being annoying?

Tags: munin

We have a Munin server that's taken to some really strange behaviour lately. The website itself is working perfectly, we're getting our statistics, I'm getting paged, everything is otherwise fine except... Every 5 minutes I'm getting an e-mail that says:

```
/bin/sh: 1: munin: not found
This program will easily break if you run it as root as you are
trying now.  Please run it as user 'munin'.  The correct 'su' command
on many systems is 'su - munin --shell=/bin/bash'
Aborting.
```

So, I figure that the crontab in /etc/cron.d/munin-node has the wrong username, right? No...

```
#
# cron-jobs for munin-node
#

MAILTO=root

# If the APT plugin is enabled, update packages databases approx. once
# an hour (12 invokations an hour, 1 in 12 chance that the update will
# happen), but ensure that there will never be more than two hour (7200
# seconds) interval between updates..
*/5 * * * *     munin if [ -x /etc/munin/plugins/apt_all ]; then munin-run apt_all update 7200 12 >/dev/null; elif [ -x /etc/munin/plugins/apt ]; then munin-run apt update 7200 12 >/dev/null; fi
```

I've even completely removed the file /etc/cron.d/munin-node and it still carries on as if it's there, and that it's trying to run as root.

And, of course, the statistics keep showing up on time. It's driving me nuts, if only because I'm getting crap e-mails every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check root's crontab ? Use `crontab -l` as root to get a listing of it. Failing that take a look in the usual places

```
/etc/crontab
/etc/cron.d
/etc/cron.*
```

Comment: Well, there it is. The usual suspects were where I looked first, but somehow the crontab from /etc/cron.d/munin-cron got entered into Root's crontab. It *was* set to run as the "munin" user, but user crontabs won't listen to that field.